# random comments on page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

my question is, how can i show random comments on a page on wordpress? in my website i got a wp page where people leaves lots of comments, i want them to show randomly and not assorted by date time, here's the code of the paginated comments, what should i do? thanks :)

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>

        <li <?php echo $oddcomment; ?>id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
            <div class="paginated-comments-number" style="float: left; color: #999; width: 30px; text-align: left;"></div>
        <?php
                if ( function_exists('get_avatar') )
                    echo get_avatar( $comment, 48 );
            ?>
            <cite><?php comment_author_link() ?> 
            </cite>
            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
            <em>Your comment is awaiting moderation.</em>
          <?php endif; ?><br />

            <small class="commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo Paginated_Comments_URL('comment-' . get_comment_ID()); ?>" title=""><?php comment_date('F jS, Y') ?> at <?php comment_time() ?></a> <?php edit_comment_link('edit','&nbsp;&nbsp;',''); ?></small>

            <?php comment_text() ?>
        </li>

    <?php
        /* Changes every other comment to a different class */
        $oddcomment = ( empty( $oddcomment ) ) ? 'class="alt" ' : '';
    ?>

    <?php endforeach; /* end for each comment */ ?>
</ol>

<p>
      <!-- Start Paginated Comments Pages -->
      <?php if ( Paginated_Comments_have_pages() ) : ?>
</p>
    <p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <!-- End Paginated Comments Pages -->

      <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

      <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
      <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

      <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
```

Comment: orderby works in WP_Query() but I don't think that wp_list_comments() takes orderby, you minght be stuck shuffling the $comments array with php, by calling "shuffle($comments);" right before your foreach loop

Comment: @Jory Cunningham for the comments or wp_list_comments i'm using a plugin called paginated comments that allows to edit the comments list and comment form manually. the code below was taken from that plug in.

Comment: Ah, ok. A quick review of that plugin didn't show any randomization functions. Try that shuffle thing I suggested, it might work...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion for a **[shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)** function that does what you're asking for:

```
add_shortcode( 'randomComment', 'randomComment_handler' );

function randomComment_handler($post_id) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '0',
        ), $atts ) );
    $out = "";
    $comments = get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve");
    if ($comments) {
        $ndx = mt_rand(0,sizeof($comments)) - 1; 
        $comment = $comments[$ndx];
        $out = "<div class='randomComment'><div class='randomAuthor'>".$comment->comment_author."</div><div class='randomText'>".$comment->comment_content."</div></div>";
    }
    return $out;
}
```

This goes into your `functions.php`, and lets you put the shortcode on any page or post to show a random comment:

```
[randomComment post_id="1337"]
```

Just change the `post_id` according to the post you want to pull the random comment from.

Comment: thanks for answering @Trollsyn see i don't want to show a random comments from a page, see what i want is for example let's say I write an article, and then in that article i get lots of comments, what i want is to show those comments randomly but in that same article, and not assorted from first to the last or ascending and descending. is that possible? :S

Comment: I didn't quite read through your question then, my apologies! :)